# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixed' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have gotten this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixed' of null.

This project includes Javascript, Reactjs, Gatsbyjs, and Contentful.

Error code section:

```
  3 | import { styles } from '../../utils'
  4 | import Img from 'gatsby-image'
  5 | 
> 6 | export default function Product({ product }) {
  7 |   const { name, price, ingredients } = product;
  8 |   const { fixed } = product.img;
  9 |
```

Existing code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { styles } from '../../utils'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

export default function Product({ product }) {
  const { name, price, ingredients } = product;
  const { fixed } = product.img;

  return (
    <ProductWrapper>
      <Img fixed={fixed} className="img" />
      <div className="text">
        <div className="product-content">
          <h3 className="name">{name}</h3>
          <h3 className="price">${price}</h3>
        </div>
        <p className="info">{ingredients}</p>
      </div>
    </ProductWrapper>
  )
}
```

Fixed is defined in Menu.js

```js
                    img {
                      fixed(width: 150, height: 150) {                            ...GatsbyContentfulFixed_tracedSVG
```

After spending many hours looking for a solution, I decided to ask for any help.

Thank you

Comment: What does Menu.js look like?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are entirely different languages. Please do not flag JS questions with the Java tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your component is rendering before product.img value is obtained. Try the below code.

```
if(product && product.img){
const { fixed } = product.img;
}

return (
    <>
{fixed 
  &&(
    <ProductWrapper>
      <Img fixed={fixed} className="img" />
      <div className="text">
        <div className="product-content">
          <h3 className="name">{name}</h3>
          <h3 className="price">${price}</h3>
        </div>
        <p className="info">{ingredients}</p>
      </div>
    </ProductWrapper>
  )
   </>
  )
```

Comment: I don't think you can reference to `fixed` since you conditionally declare `fixed`?